# Ghidra doing messy stuff at simple ADD instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ghidra

I can't figure out if ghidra is doing messy stuff @ the decompiler or I did enough reversing this day.

**Assembly:**

```
00400b76 48 83 45 f8 01       ADD        qword ptr [RBP + local_10],offset DAT_006020c1
```

**where DAT_006020c1 is:**

```
                             DAT_006020c1                                    XREF[2]:     
    006020c1 3c              undefined1 3Ch
```

So it should be a regular byte addition between local_10 and 0x3C right?

**Ghidra Decompiler output for this line:**

```
local_10 = local_10 + 1;
```

So this makes no sense to me because we don't make an addition with 0x1?

Regards

Comment: The instruction `48 83 45 xx yy`  is `add qword [rbp + xx], yy`. (You’re missing two of the instruction bytes in the first code block.) The second operand is an immediate value, not a value from memory. Apparently the immediate value is 1, not the address of  DAT_006020c1.

Comment: `add qword [rbp+something], immediate` can't be a 3-byte instruction: REX + opcode + modrm + disp8 + imm8 is 5 bytes.  Or 8 bytes if it's a 32-bit immediate.  (But in this case it's the opcode for a 1-byte sign-extended immediate.)  x86-64 can't encode an instruction with two explicit memory operands.  Note the `offset` keyword.

Comment: Fixed the missing instruction bytes now (copy/paste fault)

Comment: Okay should've noticed the opcodes 
83 45 f8 01  -> add  DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],0x1
But what does ghidra mean with this DAT_006020c1 ?
Radare and IDA translate it as 0x1

Comment: is this the only machine code you are feeding the decompiler?

Comment: no the whole function (about 100) instructions

Comment: Is this in an object file or executable with a symbol table?  IDK why an immediate `1` would get treated as any kind of symbol reference.

Comment: it's an ELFx86 with a symbol table

Comment: BTW, the decompilation makes perfect sense; the machine code clearly is just adding `1`, as an 8-bit immediate.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/add confirms that `REX.W=1 83` is the opcode for `add r/m64, imm8`.  The weird thing is the disassembly labeling the immediate as `offset DAT_006020c1`.  That would make an interesting question about ghidra's disassembler, but there's so much wrong with your assumptions in the question that it's hard to upvote.  e.g. of course it's not adding a value from somewhere else in memory, that's impossible.

Comment: i agree with your opinion, thats why i asked this question cause the disassembly makes no sense to me.